# Clear Edit Text - adb

Tags: android, adb, android-framework, android-shell

How to clear focused Edit text using shell command.

I tried

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CLEAR // Not worked 
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DEL // Delete only one char
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL // Not worked
```

With this I am only able to delete upto One character only, Is there any way I can delete/clear the focused Edit text.

Comment: try using `adb shell input text ''  `

Comment: Invalid arguments for command: text, Even If I make it run anyhow it will add new space in already input text.

Comment: I am unable to find any such command which can clear the whole edittext's data.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
function clear_input() {
    adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MOVE_END
    adb shell input keyevent --longpress $(printf 'KEYCODE_DEL %.0s' {1..250})
}
```

Then:

```
clear_input
```

Comment: What are KEYCODE_MOVE_END and KEYCODE_DEL?

Comment: KEYCODE_MOVE_END = move the cursor to the end of line

Comment: KEYCODE_DEL = delete the character in the current cursor position

Comment: I think that is not obvious and that is correct syntax because it is a constant and not an environment variable:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

Comment: I already upvoted and used your answer, but I'm just commenting to improve it. That is incorrect Bash syntax, period. Constants/variables in Bash are declared without $ but to get their value you need to prefix them with $. But hey, be my guest and avoid learning something ;)

Comment: Man, those values are constants of Android SDK, not BASH.
Please, take a look at the link this time.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MOVE_END

Answer (score 6):

This will select all and then backspace.

```
input keycombination 113 29 && input keyevent 67
```

Comment: Amazing - this should be the top-rated solution!

Comment: it works for emulator, but when I check it with Samsung mobile, I get this error 
Error: Unknown command: keycombination
Usage: input [<source>] <command> [<arg>...]

The sources are: 
      dpad
      keyboard
      mouse
      touchpad
      gamepad
      touchnavigation
      joystick
      touchscreen
      stylus
      trackball

Answer (score 4):

You can use this way:

```
adb shell input keyevent --longpress 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67
```

67 is the keycode of **KEYCODE_DEL**

Comment: Need to go to the end of the edit text, then

Answer (score 2):

If you use uiautomator(https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator), you could do this by:

1. tap the EditText widget to get focus, then
2. use `device(focused=True).clear_text()` to clear the view, or by  `device(focused=True).set_text("new text")` to set a new text.

Comment: Question is about ADB

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found so far is to get the proper coordinates to use `input swipe x y x y duration` to simulate a long press. This will then highlight all the text in the EditText field. You can then send the keys you want to replace what was there.

I just wish that `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CLEAR` would clear all the text in the field. That would make things so much easier, if someone can find a better way that would be great.