# Clear text box with adb commands

Tags: android, textbox, adb

```
adb shell input swipe 140 422 140 422 1500
```

Im using this to select all text, then press KEYCODE_DEL. But it is not really good. If the text box have characters: "-" , "@"
It will be text break.
Do anyone have other ways ? Thanks.

Comment: You can go through the following link: [Clear Edit Text - adb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453287/5155885)

Comment: I dont understand it. How to convert it to adb commands batch?

Comment: you may want to execute `input keyevent KEYCODE_DEL` several times untill all characters are deleted. Anyway best way to deal with these situation is via uiautomator-https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator